# Navbar items are not clickable and nav items at right side are not getting aligned properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

> Two navbar items i.e. **About us** and **Contact us** are not
>   clickable. How to make these navbar items clickable?
>
> and how to align one of the navbar item properly i.e. **Login** which is currently
>   positioned at rightmost part of the navbar.This login item has dropdown menu which only gets partially displayed because it is situated in rightmost part.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: black;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: catamaran;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 45px;
}

h1,
p {
  color: black;
}

h2>span {
  color: black;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  h1 {
    background-color: #449d44;
  }
  h2 {
    background-color: #449d44;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  h1 {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
}

.nav-item active {
  text-align: left;
}

#Login {
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  padding: 14px 14px 0;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/technical_landing.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">


  <title>Minimum Bootstrap HTML Skeleton</title>

  <!--  -->

  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Technical lab</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>


      </ul>



      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Log in <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul id="Login" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    Login via:
                    <div class="social-button">
                      <a href="# class=btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
                      <a href="# class=btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>
          <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                     <i class="far fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-stack-1x"></i>
                 </span>
        </h2>
        <h1>Technical lab is coming soon.</h1>
        <p>Waiting is not easy but just wait this time</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
             <i class="fas fa-spinner"></i>
             <br>Click me</button>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add a route to the `href` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your CSS:
`.navbar { z-index: 1;}`
`.navbar-nav {align-items: center;}`
`#Login {right: 0; position: absolute; left: unset;}`

Answer (score 0):

## I hope you should copy this code and use in your Html file

If Want exact result

or visit this clink for life  [Demo](https://codepen.io/mrana/pen/wvaGrWe)  for the navbar right

```css
.header {
  min-height: 500px;
 }

.rightNavbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.4.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"><nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rightNavbar navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Login
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```